# Procedurally generated objects of paintings

Tags: modeling

I have number of pictures of different paintings (all with different aspect ratios). I need to create art gallery with paintings randomly selected from this collection.

What are ways to adjust painting frame and canvas object to size of a random painting? Doing this manually is not an option.

UPD: All paintings in separate images.

UPD: Can it be done without creating whole painting frame in script? It will be pretty hard to build mesh of more complex frame.

Comment: Are all those paintings on one picture or every one of them is a separate image?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand the requirement correctly. But here is one way... The following code will create an extruded planes per image from the given directory. One of the faces of the plane will have the image texture (you can randomize the array of image files using random.shuffle).

This is rather quick and dirty :), so maybe buggy and quite slow.  To improve the performance, (and if the functionality broadly corresponds to your requirement) you'd need to replace the ops calls with the low level equivalents. Also, the space between the planes may be required to be properly worked out.

```
import bpy
import os
import glob

def getOverride():
    for area in bpy.context.window.screen.areas:
        if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
            v3d = area.spaces[0]
            rv3d = v3d.region_3d
            for region in area.regions:
                if region.type == 'WINDOW':
                    override = {
                        'scene'  : bpy.context.scene,
                        'region' : region,
                        'area'   : area,
                        'space'  : v3d
                    }
                    #~ return region, rv3d, v3d, area
                    return override
    return None


types = ["*.png", "*.jpg"]
srcDir = '/tmp/'
imageToCanvasRatio = .8
canvasThickness = .08
canvasColor = [.120,.109,0.02,1]
canvasWidth = 1
canvasOffset = .2
image_files = [os.path.basename(x) for t in types for x in glob.glob(srcDir + t)]
maxImgs = 15
maxHeight = 0
imgsPerRow = 5
cumulHeight = 0

bpy.context.scene.render.engine = 'CYCLES'

defaultMat = bpy.data.materials.new('Background')
defaultMat.use_nodes = True
node_tree = defaultMat.node_tree        
node_tree.nodes.get("Diffuse BSDF").inputs["Color"].default_value = canvasColor
for i in range(0, len(image_files), imgsPerRow):
    imgs = [bpy.data.images.load(srcDir + image_files[i + k]) for k in range(0, imgsPerRow) if (i + k) < len(image_files)]
    maxHeight = max(canvasWidth * img.size[1] / img.size[0] for img in imgs)
    for j, img in enumerate(imgs):
        print(i, j, maxImgs)
        if(i + j >= maxImgs):
            break

        canvasHeight = canvasWidth * img.size[1] / img.size[0]

        bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_plane_add(location=(2 * j * (canvasWidth + canvasOffset), cumulHeight + maxHeight/2, 0))

        obj = bpy.context.object
        obj.dimensions[0] = canvasWidth
        obj.dimensions[1] = canvasHeight

        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
        bpy.ops.mesh.extrude_region_move(MESH_OT_extrude_region={"mirror":False}, TRANSFORM_OT_translate={"value":(0, 0, canvasThickness), "constraint_axis":(False, False, True)})

        bpy.ops.mesh.loopcut_slide(getOverride(), MESH_OT_loopcut={"number_cuts":1, "edge_index":5}, TRANSFORM_OT_edge_slide={"value":imageToCanvasRatio})
        bpy.ops.mesh.loopcut_slide(getOverride(), MESH_OT_loopcut={"number_cuts":1, "edge_index":5}, TRANSFORM_OT_edge_slide={"value":-imageToCanvasRatio})
        bpy.ops.mesh.loopcut_slide(getOverride(), MESH_OT_loopcut={"number_cuts":1, "edge_index":4}, TRANSFORM_OT_edge_slide={"value":-imageToCanvasRatio})
        bpy.ops.mesh.loopcut_slide(getOverride(), MESH_OT_loopcut={"number_cuts":1, "edge_index":6}, TRANSFORM_OT_edge_slide={"value":-imageToCanvasRatio})
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')

        obj.data.materials.append(defaultMat)

        for faceIdx in range(0, len(obj.data.polygons)) :
            if(faceIdx != 24):
                obj.data.polygons[faceIdx].material_index = 0

        mat = bpy.data.materials.new('mat')
        mat.use_nodes = True
        node_tree = mat.node_tree
        node_texture = node_tree.nodes.new("ShaderNodeTexImage")
        node_texture.image = img
        links = mat.node_tree.links
        links.new(node_texture.outputs['Color'], node_tree.nodes.get("Diffuse BSDF").inputs['Color'])
        obj.data.materials.append(mat)
        obj.data.polygons[24].material_index=1
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
        bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='SELECT')
        obj.data.uv_textures.new()
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
    if(i + j >= maxImgs):
        break
    cumulHeight += (maxHeight)+ canvasOffset
```

[image]

Comment: For some reason line `obj.dimensions[0] = canvasWidth` is not setting the x dimensions. Maybe someone can look into this.

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer. But it raised a few more question. Besides painting in frame I need to change camera position and lighting conditions, first I planned to do it with animation, hence i need 1-10 actual objects, but images in them need to change every frame. Also, in this way it hard to make more complex frame, is there any way to change existing mesh. Can you explain how to run this script? Just opening in Blender's text editor and pressing run don't work.

Comment: @A.Verbitsky The script above will generate framed paintings of all png and jpg images in your "/tmp" folder.   Copy some images into tmp, or edit folder name as required. IMO Changing camera and lighting is outside the scope of the question.

Comment: For image types look at `bpy.path.extensions_image` (a set of all images that can load for that specific blender)  On the dimensions, try setting the scale instead.   Would be very tempted to leverage off import images as planes addon to load the images.

Comment: @batFINGER Yes, import images as planes may have been a better option. But since now the requirement is to have a custom frame, it needs a custom solution :)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I am giving below the code to use a custom frame. You need to create the frame object with a rectangular face that will contain the picture (see example 'frame2' in the layer below the active layer in the attached blend). The vertices of this face should be added to a vertex group (group name 'pic' in the current example). The name of the object needs to be specified in the variable frameObjName and the name of the vertex group in pcVertGrpName. Pictures are taken from directory specified in the variable srcDir (it's tmp currently). You can experiment with the other parameters.

Please refer to the attached blend file for a working example. Before running the script, you need to delete all the objects in the active layer, change the srcDir variable to point to the directory where you have the images.

This code is not at all optimized and may not suit your purpose but I hope it will serve as a starting point for building your own script.

```
import bpy
import os
import glob
import math
import random

types = bpy.path.extensions_image
srcDir = '/tmp/'
imageToCanvasRatio = .9
pixelUnits = 1000 #1000 pixel is 1 blender unit
canvasOffsetX = .8
canvasOffsetY = .4
image_files = [os.path.basename(x) for t in types for x in glob.glob(srcDir + '*'+t)]
random.shuffle(image_files)
maxImgs = 15
maxHeight = 0
imgsPerRow = 5
cumulHeight = 0
frameObjName = 'frame2'
pcVertGrpName = 'pic'
cumulWidth = 0

bpy.context.scene.render.engine = 'CYCLES'

for i in range(0, len(image_files), imgsPerRow):
    cumulWidth = 0
    imgs = [bpy.data.images.load(srcDir + image_files[i + k]) for k in range(0, imgsPerRow) if (i + k) < len(image_files)]
    maxHeight = max( (float(img.size[1]) / float(pixelUnits)) for img in imgs)
    for j, img in enumerate(imgs):

        if(i + j >= maxImgs):
            break

        canvasWidth = float(img.size[0]) / float(pixelUnits)
        canvasHeight = float(img.size[1]) / float(pixelUnits)
        frameObj = bpy.data.objects[frameObjName]
        mesh = frameObj.data.copy()
        mesh.name = 'pic'+str(i+j)+'data'
        obj = bpy.data.objects.new('pic'+str(i+j), mesh)
        bpy.context.scene.objects.link(obj)
        obj.location = [cumulWidth + canvasWidth / 2, cumulHeight + maxHeight/2, obj.location[2]]
        picVertIdxs = [v.index for v in frameObj.data.vertices if (frameObj.vertex_groups[pcVertGrpName].index in [g.group for g in v.groups])]
        for vI in picVertIdxs:
            obj.data.vertices[vI].select = True
        obj.select = True
        bpy.context.scene.objects.active = obj            

        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
        bbox = [(min(obj.data.vertices[j].co[i] for j in picVertIdxs), max(obj.data.vertices[j].co[i] for j in picVertIdxs)) for i in range(0, 3)]
        bboxW = bbox[0][1]-bbox[0][0]
        bboxH = bbox[1][1]-bbox[1][0]
        scaleW = canvasWidth / bboxW
        scaleH = canvasHeight / bboxH

        bpy.ops.transform.resize(value=(scaleW, 0, 0), constraint_axis=(True, False, False), constraint_orientation='GLOBAL', mirror=False, proportional='CONNECTED', proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=10)
        bpy.ops.transform.resize(value=(0, scaleH, 0), constraint_axis=(False, True, False), constraint_orientation='GLOBAL', mirror=False, proportional='CONNECTED', proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=10)

        bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action="DESELECT")

        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')


        mat = bpy.data.materials.new('mat')
        mat.use_nodes = True
        node_tree = mat.node_tree
        node_texture = node_tree.nodes.new("ShaderNodeTexImage")
        node_texture.image = img
        links = mat.node_tree.links
        links.new(node_texture.outputs['Color'], node_tree.nodes.get("Diffuse BSDF").inputs['Color'])

        obj.data.materials.append(mat)
        polyIdx = [f for f in obj.data.polygons if len(set(v for v in f.vertices).intersection(set(picVertIdxs))) == len(f.vertices)][0].index
        obj.data.polygons[polyIdx].material_index=len(obj.data.materials)-1
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
        bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='SELECT')
        obj.data.uv_textures.new()
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')

        cumulWidth += (canvasWidth + canvasOffsetX)

    if(i + j >= maxImgs):
        break
    cumulHeight += (maxHeight)+ canvasOffsetY
```